# Writing NDSolve-like functions

Tags: differential-equations, function-construction

I've been using *Mathematica* for a while now, and there are multiple common tasks that I end up doing. I'd like to learn how to convert them into functions so that I can store them in some file and load them at startup.

Most of these common tasks involve taking a set of equations and doing something with them. Thing is, I don't want to fix the variables the equations are written in, and would like behavior similar to `NDSolve` where one can specify the functions as well as which variable is which.

For example, take this task:

```
Pd = ParametricNDSolve[{v'[t] == (v[t] - v[t]^3/3 - ω[t])/0.2, 
       ω'[t] == (1 + v[t])/0.2, 
       ω[0] == b, v[0] == a}, {v[t], ω[t]}, 
        {t, 0, 20}, {a, b}];
PVec[x_, y_] := {D[(v[t] /. Pd) [x, y], t] /. t -> 0, 
                 D[(ω[t] /. Pd) [x, y], t] /. t -> 0};
VectorPlot[PVec[x, y], {x, -2, 1}, {y, -1.2, 0.5}]
```

Here, I'm parametrically solving the pair of equations

$$
\begin{align}
v'(t)&=\frac{-\frac{1}{3} v(t)^3+v(t)-\omega (t)}{0.2}\\
\omega'(t)&=\frac{v(t)+1}{0.2}
\end{align}
$$

with the parameters being the initial state of $v$ and $\omega$. Now, I take the vector field of their derivatives at $t=0$, and vector plot it. Basically, I want to get a quick map of how the initial trajectories ($(v'(t),\omega'(t))$) change for different initial conditions without having to open `EquationTrekker` and do things manually.

---

So now, I want to take this task and write it as a function akin to `TrajectoryMap[{eqn1,eqn2},{{var1,varmin,varmax},{var2,varmin,varmax}},{{timevar,timepoint},tmin,tmax,tpoint}]` where this particular code would run as

```
TrajectoryMap[{v'[t] == (v[t] - v[t]^3/3 - ω[t])/0.2, 
    ω'[t] == (1 + v[t])/0.2}, {{v[t],-2,1}, {ω[t],-1.2,0.5}}, {{t,0},0,20}]
```

(or something similar)

Here, `timepoint` is the value of `t` for which the derivative of the interpolating function is calculated.

I can tell that this will probably need some combination of `Hold`s and `Evaluate`s, but I can't seem to get the right one.

How should I go about converting this code (or any arbitrary code of a similar type) into a custom function?

Comment: If I understood it correctly, you want `TrajectoryMap[...]` to do what is being done in the code block above, right? If so, where do you specify the ICs and the plot ranges?

Comment: @rm-rf The ICs are the `ParametricNDSolve` parameters, they get substituted with `x,y` later on. The vector plot is a plot of $(v'(t),\omega'(t))$ at various initial conditions. The plot ranges are specified in the `{{v[t],-2,1}, {ω[t],-1.2,0.5}}` (i.e. the `{{var1,varmin,varmax},{var2,varmin,varmax}}`) part.

Comment: Yes, but for a generic function, shouldn't you allow for an IC point other than 0 and `t` other than 0–20?

Comment: @rm-rf Well, if that can be genericized I don't mind, but when I use this set of code I usually don't need much of a range for `t` -- in fact, none at all. I'll add that bit, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To construct a generic function that takes a set of equations, variables, limits and plots the output per your code above, you'll need to ensure that the variables (`v`, `ω` and `t`) are properly localized and that global values do not enter your implementation. You can do this with a combination of `Block` and attributes (ignore the red):

```
ClearAll@TrajectoryMap
SetAttributes[TrajectoryMap, HoldAll]
TrajectoryMap[
    {eqns__}, 
    {{xvar_, xmin_, xmax_}, {yvar_, ymin_, ymax_}}, 
    {{t_, init_}, tmin_, tmax_}] := 

Block[{t, xvar, yvar, a, b, Pd, PVec},
    Pd = ParametricNDSolve[{eqns, xvar[init] == a, yvar[init] == b}, 
        {xvar[t], yvar[t]}, {t, tmin, tmax}, {a, b}];
    PVec[x_, y_] := {D[(xvar[t] /. Pd)[x, y], t] /. t -> init, 
        D[(yvar[t] /. Pd)[x, y], t] /. t -> init};
    VectorPlot[PVec[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}]
]
```

Now you can use this for any set of equations and variables as (using your example):

```
TrajectoryMap[
    {v'[t] == (v[t] - v[t]^3/3 - ω[t])/0.2, ω'[t] == (1 + v[t])/0.2}, 
    {{v, -2, 1}, {ω, -1.2, 0.5}}, {{t, 0}, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

which is what your example produces.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `SetAttributes`,  (or `Block`, I've been using `Module` which is lexical.), which must be where I went wrong. I also didn't know about the ability to use lists in the function declaration itself. I think that there may be a syntax error here, though, the `t,xvar,yvar` shouldn't be in the `Block` statement. Not sure.

Comment: Nope, not a syntax error. As I said in my answer, ignore the red :) If you want to see why, remove them from `Block` and redefine `TrajectoryMap`, evaluate `t = v = ω = 1;`, followed by the `TrajectoryMap[...]` line.

Comment: It seems to work both ways, though. What's the difference? Is it preventing the variables from messing with outside variables?

Comment: @Manishearth I updated my comment while you were writing yours... please see my previous comment. Yes, it is what you said.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Why does it work in this case though? When I try `t = 5; Print[t]; Block[{t}, Print[t]; t = 6;]; Print[t]`, the `t` in the block is taken as a fresh variable. Whereas here it seems to be substituted in from the outside.

Comment: @Manishearth I don't understand your question... in both cases `Block` works exactly as it should. Think of `Block` as being a "temporary memory erase" for a symbol. Once outside the `Block` scope, it behaves as it normally would.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind. It's only being used on the symbol inputs, now I think I got it. Thanks :)